# Parsing txt file into csv

Tags: python, csv, parsing

i need to parse some .txt file into .csv!
Let's begin... Text file looks like that:

> COMPACT3
>
> GPS_START_TIME 2010  4 15 00 00  0.0000
>
> 0.0000 10 G16 G02 G29 G31 G30 G12 G10 G21 G05 G24
>
> 0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000
>       30.0000 -1
>
> -0.050     0.049    -0.007    -0.003    -0.015    -0.006    -0.036
>   0.020     0.049    -0.002
>       60.0000 -1
>
> ....

First three rows are header and then follow a lot of data that need to be processed. "-1" represent EOL (end of line)!

.csv must be in this format:

> time G16 G02 G29 G31 G30 G12 G10 G21 G05 G24
>
> time is the number before "-1", in our example 30.000, 60.000, etc
>
> G16 G02 ... are first 10 numbers in the row

Any help how to parse that .txt file into .csv?

Comment: Have you tried writing some code to do that? You may have confused SO with some sort of code-writing or tutorial service, which it isn't.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the tour and how to ask. Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider.

Answer (score 0):

you'll find how to read and write files here :

for python2.7 : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

for python3 : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

and then may use things like : 
readline(), str.split(), etc...

but please send some code you have done